# Find very last dot in text with regexp

Tags: regex

I have a text like this and I want to find the last dot with regexp (the last dot after the last word which is "pariatur" in this case and don't have anything after).

*Example text:*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

I know how to find last dot in a string but that gives me the last dot in all sentences but I only want the very last one. Thanks.

Comment: Finding the last dot means? Finding its position? Or whether it checks the given sentence got last period?

Comment: just use `lastIndexOf` or whatever you have in your language. No need for regexp

Comment: Do you need the text before last dot from the end?

Comment: ```.*\.``` matches the last dot explicitely (since the star is greedy). According to the language you use, you can make it a group and perform further actions with it.

Comment: Thanks, that i want is to find the last character in the texteditor (will be a dot in this case) with regexp because im using a search and replace add on for Firefox that allows me to use regexp. I want to replace last dot with .</p> for a lot of tabs where each one needs to get this .</p> in the very end of the everything in the editor. Its a Wordpress site where i paste the .</p> in the editor field for many pages.

Comment: @Danstahr Tested with .*\. but i only want the last dot like i describe in my previous comment.

Comment: So just make it a group (like ```.*(\.)```). From here, things become language specific.

Comment: Just .*(\.) ? or exactly how to get only last dot? I'm new to regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is a modifier which can turn on to treat the whole line as a single text.

Generally it is the 's'.

The details for php:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are
> excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A
> negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,
> independent of the setting of this modifier.

Comment: Or "m" modifier to searching in multi line text?

Comment: The 'm' modifies the behaviour of ^ and $ only. I think you need the s to solve the problem. (The terminology is a bit confusing...)

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. I was wrong, sorry.